# Tapping an image to move to next View

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Scenario: User is viewing a screen with an image and some accompanying text in labels.  User taps image and is brought to a screen that has the image only, and it needs to be zoomable.  User taps that image and is brought back to the image/text screen.

Using storyboards I have implemented the first screen with

```
 @interface FirstImageViewController :  UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

That works. (btw though, I do not have zoom working on this screen)
I implemented the second screen  with

```
 @interface SecondImageViewController : UIViewController  <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

I tried to segue to the second screen with:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SingleImage" sender:touch]; 
return YES;
```

and

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
   self.secondImageViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    [self.secondImageViewController setImageToDisplay:self.imageToDisplay];
 }
```

but get an error on the gestureRecognizer method:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key imageDisplayer.'

I am not sure I am going about this the right way and could use help.

Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message is most often a symptom of a problem in your UI (whether xib or storyboard) where a view controller and its associated views are being loaded and there's a reference to an outlet that doesn't exist in code.  Do you have a link in your storyboard to something called `imageDisplayer`?

(If you don't see it, try right-clicking on your storyboard and choosing "Open As->Source Code" and doing a text search.)

Comment: yes, I am using storyboards and yes to your question --- in the source for the storyboard is a <connections> list and inside that is is <outlet property="imageDisplayer" destination="JS2-2t-EuY" id="VA3-yu-jhT"/>.  btw - the name of my segue is "SingleImage"

Comment: p.s. My FirstImageViewController has two segues.  One segue from a button (flip side view) is working, and then this broken seque (Single Image) is from the First Image View Controller.  Maybe this is where my error is.  I bet you are right that it is in my story board.

Comment: So, you need to find the storyboard object that contains that outlet and remove the connection.  Either that or -- if you need it -- declare a matching IBOutlet in that object's code.

Comment: Yup. So now I know the answer was right in the error message.  Thanks so much for your help and patience.

Comment: True...though I wonder if it would have killed the developer to write an error message that said, "Encountered an unmatched 'imageDisplayer' link while loading a <whatever> object from scene <X> of storyboard <Y>."  :-)